# Laurent series for $1/(e^z-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Trying to compute the first five coefficients of the Laurent series for $$\frac{1}{e^z-1}$$ centered at the point $0$. I'm not seeing a way to use the geometric series due to the exponential. Any ideas?

Comment: The Laurent series with respect to which point?

Comment: Centered at the point $0$.

Comment: I assume you're interested in the series that converges on the punctured disc of radius $2\pi$, and not one of the ones that converges on an annulus (whose inner and outer radii are both multiples of $2\pi$)?

Comment: Yes, the first one.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this formally. Since $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ has a simple pole at $0$, it must have a Laurent series with no coefficient of $z^k$ for $k<-1$. If the coefficient of $z^k$ is $a_k$, we must then have

$$\left(\frac{a_{-1}}{z}+a_0+a_1z+a_2 z^{2} + a_3z^3+ O(z^4)\right)\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+O(z^6)\right)=1$$

and you can multiply this out and equate coefficients to find the values of the $a_i$. For example, equating order-zero coefficients immediately gives $a_{-1}=1$. Equating order-one coefficients gives $\frac{a_{-1}}{2}+a_0=0$, so $a_0=-\frac{1}{2}$. Equating order-two coefficients gives $\frac{a_{-1}}{6}+\frac{a_0}{2}+a_1=0$, and so $a_1=-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$; and so on.

Comment: I believe that this method is closest to what is looked for in an intro to complex variables class.

Comment: This is the answer I would have given, too, but I would have given a different method of finding the coefficients. You set up a long division problem à la high-school math, but run the terms in the opposite direction, that is, increasing degrees as you go left to right. You’re dividing the standard series for $e^x-1$ into $1$, and do your thing. Of course it gets messy after a while, but there are no undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 7):

Consider that $e^z-1$ has a simple zero in $z=0$, since:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1.$$
This gives that $z=0$ is a simple pole for $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ with residue $1$, hence
$$ g(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}-\frac{1}{z}$$
is a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of zero.

The coefficients of the Taylor series of $g(z)$ depend on the Bernoulli numbers, since we have:
$$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n,$$
giving:

> $$\frac{1}{e^z-1}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{B_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}z^n.$$