# Show that the formal power series $ Q(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}$ has the property that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $Q(x)^{n+1}$ is always $1$

Tags: combinatorics, differential-geometry, generating-functions

When I am looking up the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_class) for the definition of Todd class, it says that the formal power series defined by
$$
Q(x)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}}=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^4}{720}+\cdots$$
has the property that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $Q(x)^{n+1}$ is always $1$. It seems that this property does not immediately follow from the definition. How can we show that $Q(x)$ satisfies this property and if a power series satisfies this property, then it must be $Q(x)$?

Comment: The coefficients in question can be computed using the definition and properties of the Nörlund numbers and the Stirling numbers of the first kind:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{| t | < 1 } \left( \frac{t}{1 - e^{ - t} } \right)^{n + 1} \frac{dt}{t^{n + 1} }  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{| t | < 1 } \frac{dt}{(1 - e^{ - t} )^{n + 1} }  \\ = \mathop {\mathrm{ Res}}\limits_{t = 0} \frac{1}{(1 - e^{ - t} )^{n + 1} } = ( - 1)^n \frac{B_n^{(n + 1)} }{n!} = ( - 1)^n \frac{s(n + 1,1)}{n!} = 1.
$$

Comment: Else, one needs  to show  that $$\frac{d^p}{dx^p} (\frac{x}{(1-e^{-x})})^{p+1}|_{x=0}=p!.$$

Answer (score 2):

A way to circumvent "laborious" computations is to use [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Applied to $z=f(w):=1-e^{-w}$ around $w=0$, it gives $w=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(g_n/n!)z^n$, where $$g_n=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{w}{1-e^{-w}}\right)^n\Bigg|_{w=0}=(n-1)![w^{n-1}]Q(w)^n\qquad(n>0)$$ and, knowing that $-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n$, we get $[w^{n-1}]Q(w)^n=1$ for all $n>0$.

Comment: (Given $[x^n]Q(x)^{n+1}$, the $Q(x)$ itself is unique, so the other direction is immediate.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering if  there is a more combinatorial approach?